# POWER BI If the query return 0 change the previous value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image: MY TABLE HERE]

I have this table and from the money table i want to cut the money per month , each month is 260 but if the amount is less than 20 i want the value to be 20 and then previous value -20 . Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution here would be calculate(
if & else) but i'm not sure if it would work if you give more details about the issue, it's very clear for the -20 part?